# How can I pass a prop from the child component to a parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

I have a updateServerStatusModal component which is being used in the servers.js component. I am trying to pass a prop from the updateServerStatusModal component to the servers component, but it doesn't seem to work correctly after a couple of different trials.

updateServerStatusModal component

```
...other imports
import Select from './Select'

const UpdateServerStatusModal = ({
    open,
    setOpen,
    title = '',
    confirmBtnTitle = 'Delete',
    variant = 'alert',
    onConfirm,
    icon = 'exclamation',
    onStatusChange,
}) => {

    const handleConfirm = async event => {
        await onConfirm(selectedStatus)
    }

    const statusList = [
        { id: 1, label: 'active' },
        { id: 2, label: 'full' },
        { id: 3, label: 'inactive' },
    ]
    const [selectedStatus, setSelectedStatus] = useState(statusList[0].label)

    return (
        <Modal open={!!open} setOpen={setOpen} width={464}>
            <Modal.Title>
                {icons[icon]}
                <span>{title}</span>
            </Modal.Title>
            <Select
                idKey="id"
                labelKey="label"
                value={selectedStatus}
                placeholder="Select type"
                onChange={label => {
                    setSelectedStatus(label)
                    if (onStatusChange) {
                        onStatusChange(label)
                    }
                }}
                list={statusList}
            />

            <div>
                <Button
                    onClick={handleConfirm}
                >
                    confirmBtnTitle
                </Button>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    )
}

export default UpdateServerStatusModal
```

servers component

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from '@/lib/axios'
import Dropdown from '@/components/Dropdown'
import UpdateServerStatusModal from '@/components/updateServerStatusModal'

const Servers = () => {
    const [servers, setServers] = useState(null)
    const [selectedStatus, setSelectedStatus] = useState('')

    const handleUpdateStatus = server => {
        handleModalOpen(true, {
            title: 'Update Server Status',
            text: <span>Are you sure you want to update server status</span>,
            confirmText: 'Update Status',
            type: 'info',
            onConfirm: async () => {
                try {
                    await axios.put(`/api/servers/${server?.uuid}`, {
                        status: selectedStatus,
                    })
                }
            },
        })
    }

    return (
            <UpdateServerStatusModal
                open={modalProps?.open}
                setOpen={handleModalOpen}
                title={modalProps?.title}
                description={modalProps?.text}
                confirmBtnTitle={modalProps?.confirmText}
                variant={modalProps?.type}
                onConfirm={modalProps?.onConfirm}
                onStatusChange={newStatus => setSelectedStatus(newStatus)}
            />
    )
}

export default Servers
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Data down, events up. You don't pass props outward. Revise to be more clear about what "a prop" is and where you're trying to pass it, please.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use callback functions to pass props to parent component from child component.

Parent Component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [dataFromChild, setDataFromChild] = useState();

  const getDataFromChildHandler = (data) => {
    setDataFromChild(data);
  };

  return (
      <ChildComponent onDataFromChild={getDataFromChildHandler} />
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

Child Component:

```
import React from 'react';

const ChildComponent = ({ onDataFromChild }) => {

  const sendDataToParentHandler = () => {
    const data = "data from child component";

    onDataFromChild(data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={sendDataToParentHandler}>Send To Parent</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```